# How to enable the Code/Syntax highlighting for groovy in VI?

Tags: groovy, vi

i was using Fedora for about six months. Recently I have been changed to Ubuntu. And here in Ubuntu, there is no Code/Synatax for groovy in VI editor,which was actually there in Fedora VI. How to enable that? and if this not possible, then suggest me some good IDE's for Groovy(only for Groovy), so that i can increase my skill over the groovy language :):)

Don't suggest some advanced IDE, because this is the first time I'm going to use IDE in my life :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with VI or rather VIM, there are two extensions that will help you developing Groovy scripts:

[Syntax highlighting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=945)

[File type detection](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2217) -  execute Groovy scripts using the `F4`-key